# Remove an element from vector based on index not working C++ Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, vector

I have a Vector that accepts  map objects as elements where Student is a class that contains name and Id of group of a student.
After storing the  maps into the vector,now I want to delete a map based on the index or based on the map itself.That means if I want to delete map2 in vector then it should it delete map2 or the second element. I have used erase,iterator etc for deleting the elements but when I use iterator I get the following error:

> Error 3   error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Student' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

When I use:

> coll.erase(coll.begin()+2);

I can able to delete only the end/last element of the vector no matter what index I provide, but not the map that is at the position 2.

**My Program:**

```
#include <map>  
#include <iostream>  
#include "student.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

static int i=0,j=1;
vector<map<int,Student>> coll;
typedef std::map<int,Student> Mymap;  
Mymap c1;

map<int, Student> mine(int key,Student value)
{   

    c1.insert(Mymap::value_type( key,value));   
    return c1;   
}   

void print(Mymap a)
{

Mymap m2;
coll.push_back(a);
m2 = coll[i];
i++;
Student s1 = m2.at(j);
j++;

}
int main()
{
     typedef  map<int, Student> map1;  
     Student s[5];
     Student s1;
     map1 m1;
     s[0].setName("SAI");
     s[1].setName("RAVI");
     s[2].setName("RAJU");
     s[3].setName("HemaChandra");
     s[4].setName("Tushar");

     s[0].setId(10);
     s[1].setId(20);
     s[2].setId(30);
     s[3].setId(40);
     s[4].setId(50);

     m1 =  mine(1,s[0]);
     s1 = m1.at(1);   
     print(m1);

     m1 = mine(2,s[1]);
     s1 = m1.at(2);   
     print(m1);

     m1 = mine(3,s[2]);
     s1 = m1.at(3);   
     print(m1);

     m1 =  mine(4,s[3]);
     s1 = m1.at(4);
     print(m1);

     m1 =  mine(5,s[4]);
     s1 = m1.at(5);
     print(m1);

      cout<<endl<<endl;

      cout<<"Before Deleting"<<endl;
      for(int i=0,j=1;i<coll.size();i++,j++)
    {
        Mymap m3 = coll[i];
        Student st = m3.at(j);
        std::cout <<" "<< st.getName()<<std::endl;
    }

      cout<<"\nAfter Deleting"<<endl;

      coll.erase(coll.begin()+2);

    //  coll.erase(std::remove(coll.begin(), coll.end(), m1), coll.end()); -------Error when using this statement

    for(int i=0,j=1;i<coll.size();i++,j++)
    {
        Mymap m3 = coll[i];
        Student st = m3.at(j);
        std::cout <<" "<< st.getName()<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Student.cpp**

```
   #include "student.h"

void Student :: setName(string nam)
{
        name = nam;
}
void Student :: setId(int i)
{
        id = i;
}
string Student :: getName()
{
       return name;
}
int Student :: getId()
{
       return id;
}
```

**Student.h:**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
public:
    string name;
    int id;
    void  setName(string nam);
    void  setId(int i);
    string  getName();
    int getId();

};
```

All I need is, I want to delete the map at a particular position from the vector. That is, if I want to delete the map at position 2 that map should be deleted and if I want to delete the map at position "n" that nth map should be deleted. Please help me in fixing this. I am unable to find where I am doing a mistake.

I get the following compiler errors when I use erase() function:

[image: Errors in Visual Studio 2012]

Comment: Show the code for `Student`.  Looks like you are missing a comparison operator.

Comment: Thanks. I added the programs

Comment: Thanks for your help.But I didn't get you. Where should I use std::advance in the program?

Comment: @HemaChandra nvm i misread your code.

Comment: I have also added the errors. Thanks

Comment: Could you please create a [mcve] that showcases the problem, ideally something that could be copy-pasted into an online compiler like [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You probabbly need to implement the operator== in your class wStudent

Comment: @dyp it's map::erase that's failing, but yes that is correct.

Comment: @Borgleader Also, it's a map int -> Student, so the map only needs `<` on ints.

Comment: @dyp From edited code: `//  coll.erase(std::remove(coll.begin(), coll.end(), m1), coll.end()); -------Error when using this statement` this would need to compare since were erasing a value.

Comment: I need to remove a map from a group of maps that are stored in a vector

Comment: @Borgleader D'oh! that's so far to the right I haven't seen it.